# Sonarqube didn't detect common bugs in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, sonarqube, software-quality

I just tried scanning one of my Laravel based project using sonarqube cloud. But it didn't detect `missing semicolans` as an issue? Here is the code I tried.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\City;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CitiesController extends Controller
{
  public function generateShareImage(Request $request)
  {
    echo "Testing sonarqube"
    try {
        if ($request->city_name) {
            $city = City::where('name_en', $request->city_name)->first();
            $city->generateShareImage()
            return response()->json($city->id)
        }
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        throw $th;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you using it? What are the exact steps you took, and what are the results you saw?

Comment: @JamesClarkDeveloper, Created a public repository in GitHub and imported it in to sonarcloud.io with default configs.